# Lazy loading in uicollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

here is the code for my collectionview it is showing records but loading really please tell me how can i implement lazy loading on this i also have a placeholder pic in my project

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MJCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Setup image name
    NSString *url = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmllink];
    UIImage *img = nil;
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    cell.MJImageView.image = img;
    return cell;
}
```

right now it is working but very very slow.

Comment: Use SDWebImage or AsyncImageView to load image quickly and aysnchronously.

Comment: load the image asynchronously. Othewise UI thread has to wait for the image to be downloaded. That' why it's slow.

Comment: that is the my point. how am i going to do that how can apply any technique to my code? can you explain through my code!

Comment: Please do not use Mr Phuc 87 code! Look for azat92 answer. And name variables start with lowercase character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do lazy loading using GCD.

```
    // Create a queue for the operations
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("photoList", NULL);

    // Start getting the data in the background
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSData* photoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:object.photoURL]];
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];

        // Once we get the data, update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           cell.photoImageView.image = image;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to implement that is use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library, it does right what you need. There is `UIImageView` category that will allow you to modify code for that:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MJCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Setup image name
    NSString *url = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmllink];
    [cell.MJImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"url.com"]];

UIActivityIndicatorView * indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[yourImageView addSubview:indicator];
indicator.center = yourImageView.center;
[indicator startAnimating];
[yourImageView setImageWithURLRequest:request
                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                                        yourImageView.image = image;
                               });

                     [indicator stopAnimating];
                     [indicator removeFromSuperview];

} failure:nil];
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that this method is for AFNetworking.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, because your image is so large
You can use NSThread for loading

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MJCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.tag = indexPath.row; //For index
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadImage:) toTarget:self withObject:cell];
    return cell;
}

- (void) loadImage:(CollectionViewCell *)cell {
  NSString *url = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:cell.tag]xmllink];
    UIImage *img = nil;
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    cell.MJImageView.image = img;
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked but entries keep on switching from one cell to another!

Comment: and how can i use a placeholder image if image is not available or not loaded yet

Comment: On collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:, you can set a default image 'invailable', when thread completed load image, the new image will replace it.

Comment: Please do not use this code! You must set image when loaded in main queue!! Look for @azat92 answer. `SDWebImage` also allow you increase performance when working with collection view. E.c.: cancel image loading when cell is reuse. Also `SDWebImage` automaticly cache images, prepare for display in background queue.